# Automapping ajax data during ajax put or post in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

During ajax get request, we can use ko.mapping.fromJS to get data from server and do automapping. Also, we can use ko.mapping.toJS to post or put ajax data to server in knockout.

However, the assumption is that every value in ko.mapping.toJS will be pass back in ajax call. We could use delete or ignore to remove the property that should not pass back to server.

Recently, I have came to a problem as follow. How could I pass the data I want without explicitly assign or ignore the data one by one as it is too cumbersome. I am thinking that restructuring the view model may do the job but does not know how to start.

```js
function MyViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  // these data should not be pass in ajax call
  self.data1 = ko.observable();
  self.data2 = ko.observable();
  self.data3 = ko.observable();
  ...
  self.data50 = ko.observable();
  
  // these data should not be pass in ajax call
  self.noData1 = ko.observable();
  ...
  self.noData10 = ko.observable();
  
 // these should not be pass in ajax call
  self.function1 = function() { }
  self.function2 = function() { }
  self.function3 = function() { 
     $.ajax({
       ..
       type: 'POST',
       data: { ko.mapping.toJS(self) },
       success: {}  
  }
  ...
  self.function50 = function() {}
};

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well there is a technique , I call it *grouping the required set* without disturbing the 2 way binding and other dependencies .

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function (first, last, age) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    this.include = { // this set you can pass in you ajax call & skip remaining .
        lastName: ko.observable(last),
        age: ko.observable(age)
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth", 25));
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/27182/)** with preview showing everything intact .

**PS:** IMHO its not a wise way to alter/rebuild our viewModel (in complex applications maintainability can be at stake)

Comment: are you suggesting that the approach you show is not a wise way?

Comment: @stackdisplay As far method goes its the way to go(simple). for the sake of posting required data(via ajax POST)  building viewModel to suit such terms wouldn't be that wise (just an opinion tough it works perfectly to your scenario).

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it was sort of like @super cool's, except I had DTO's for to/from server that were JavaScript objects, but the properties still matched my model.

```
//use this for server interaction
var personFromDto = function(Person) {
    this.Name = Person.Name;
    this.Phone = Person.Phone;
}
var personToDto = function(Person) {
    this.Name = Person.Name();
    this.Phone = Person.Phone();
}
```

and you can always map that to your observable model representation as well.

```
var Person = function(Person) {
   this.Name = ko.observable(Person.Name);
   this.Phone = ko.observable(Person.Phone);
}
```

Just one of many ways I'm sure you could do it.

Comment: why Person.Name in personFromDto does not have() but in personToDto it have (). And how can i pass personToDto into ajax in var Person = function(Person)?

Comment: Because we are loading data from the server into a JavaScript model that matches what we expect

Comment: Yeah, you're doing something wrong. You have 2 var Person

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle but it seems i can't access personToDto inside persion view model. http://jsfiddle.net/kjv8Ldt9/

Comment: PersonToDto is a function that also accepts a parameter. You're trying to access it simply as an object or something.

Comment: so what i can do  to pass PersonToDto inside ko.toJSON?

Comment: Well you need to get the Name and Phone observables into the parameter. I'm not at a computer right now but something like personToDto(Person);